# How to integrate Hippo cms into eclipse?

Tags: spring-mvc

1. Configure of Hippo CMS in spring Bean XML.
2. Which method of CMS API to call.
3. How to Configure in Eclipse

Comment: want to try integrate Hippo cms to spring MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this page ? 
http://www.onehippo.org/library/development/import-a-project-into-eclipse.html

If you have more questions , you could also ask the Hippo community at  http://www.onehippo.org/library/about/cms-forums.html

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include a summary of the relevant parts of the links? As it stands if those links stop working then your answer becomes worthless.

Comment: How to add to my project jsp page @Anoop

Answer (score 1):

Please execute the following commands in a console beforehand:

```
1. mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate \
  -DarchetypeRepository=https://maven.onehippo.com/maven2 \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.onehippo.cms7 \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=hippo-project-archetype \
  -DarchetypeVersion=12.0.0
```

When asked to confirm the properties configuration, answer 'Y' to accept the defaults.

```
2. cd myhippoproject

3. Execute this command: mvn verify
```

Once it is succesfully completed. Please import it in eclipse as a maven project.